# Carrierwave multiple uploads fails with mount_uploaders

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave

I'm using a new way to add multiple files with carrierware as describle here:  https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#multiple-file-uploads

When I try save the object I got this error:

```
Invalid JSON text: "Invalid value." at position 1 in value (or column) '---
- photo1.jpg
- photo2.jpg
'.
```

Using:
Rails 4.2.1
MySQL 5.7.10
Ruby  2.2.2

Does anyone know what can it be?

--

I fix it migrating my project from MySQL to PostgreSQL.

Comment: did you fixed you problem? I am having the same issue here.

Comment: @ccr Yes, I fix. It's was a problem with MySQL. I migrate the project to PostgreSQL and everything works fine. I think it's a bug with MySQL

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem here on mysql and rails 4 with Carrierwave multiple upload files(images here), 
I added this to my model.rb:

```
serialize :menu_images, JSON
```

under the

```
mount_uploaders :menu_images, AvatarUploader
```

of course :menu_images is the column name for multiple files. 
It fixed the problem, no need to change the database.

Sincerely yours.

Comment: Thank you, this save me lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

You were probably reading the carrierwave documentation on the [master branch](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave) on github.

If you have the following in your Gemfile:

```
gem 'carrierwave'
```

Then at the time of writing you would have carrierwave 0.11.2 installed.

The `mount_uploaders` method is not available in this version, it is [currently on the master branch](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/issues/1551#issuecomment-71112040).

If you want to you want to use this method, you should add this line to your Gemfile instead:

```
gem 'carrierwave', github: 'carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave'
```

This will fix your issue.